# What's (technically) the difference between state management and using $rootScope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, flux, rootscope, state-management

I was using AngularJS a lot and I often read "don't over use $rootScope, it's bad practice".

Then, when React came up with the Flux pattern there was one central place for all data, which remembered me on $rootScope.

If I would use the $rootScope object as the single source of truth, what would be the difference to other approaches like Flux?

I mean, you could also just use $rootScope to organize the data, like for example $rootScope.loggedInUser, $rootScope.userList and so on. And you could make a service where all $rootScope changes will be made, so that you know where to look, when something happens.

Would be nice if someone could explain why this wouldn't be a good idea (or telling me, that it's basically okay. Im open) :)

Edit: Related question doesn't answer the question about the difference of $rootScope and Flux pattern.

Comment: Well, instead of assigning lots of properties to the `$rootScope` you are better of storing the data in a `service`. Then inject that service instead of injecting the `$rootScope`.

Comment: Read [AngularJS FAQ - `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is overusing `$rootScope` a bad practice?

The examples you are giving are better of to be stored inside a `service` or `factory`.

This way you can organize all the data and inject the correct data when ever needed.

By storing such properties inside the `$rootScope`, you end up with a huge object containing all sorts of data. Which makes it very hard to maintain if the project gets bigger.

If designing your application correctly, you won't even need the `$rootScope`.

Of course you could store everything inside the `$rootScope`, but you make it yourself and your collegues hard to maintain the application. And note that each variable set at the `$rootScope` are available to the controller `$scope` via prototypical inheritance.

[image]

Above picture is a `console.log($scope)`. As you can see the `$rootScope` data is also available through there.

Storing simple things inside the `$rootScope` could be handy sometimes ofcourse. But I can't figure out what kind of thing I would assign to the `$rootScope`. Preferably store it inside `services`.

Comment: And note that each $scope also has a copy of the $rootScope. --- NO

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yeah, updated